# Creating a loop with curl -F argument

Tags: bash, loops, curl

I have this bash script code:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/home/user/Downloads/asd/
for f in $FILES
do
curl -F dir="@/home/user/Downloads/asd;$f" -F Match=3 -F "Name=DrKla" \  
-F countNo=1 -F outputFormat=json "http://somelink.com"
done
```

Inside the `asd` folder there are 6 files and I want them to be uploaded 1 by 1 with this code as an argument of `-F "dir=@...."`

When I run my code I get the error:

> Warning: skip unknown form field: /home/user/Downloads/asd/
>
> curl: (43) A libcurl function was given a bad argument

Here is a working version of the code for a single file:

```
curl -F dir="@/home/user/Downloads/asd/count.txt" -F Match=3 -F "Name=DrKla" \  
-F countNo=1 -F outputFormat=json "http://somelink.com"
```

So I want to have all the files in `asd` folder to be read and uploaded like this. I don't see what's wrong with my do loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues appear to be that you only give a path, not a reference to all files in the path `*` and there is a strange semi-colon `;` in your path:

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/home/user/Downloads/asd/*
for f in $FILES
do
    curl -F dir="@$f" -F Match=3 -F "Name=DrKla" \  
         -F countNo=1 -F outputFormat=json "http://somelink.com"
done
```

I'm not sure what the `@` is for or if it is needed, but `$f` should already contain the path.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much with this exact code it works. I honestly don't know why the @ is there but it is a must it seems cus when I delete it code does not work. But this version of what you gave works like a charm. Thank you